# How to use "<<" operator in XPATH 2.0?

Tags: xslt, operator-precedence, xpath-2.0

I am studying the concept of Node comparison in XPath 2.0.
I am working with precedes operator `<<` and getting an error below:

> The value of attribute "select" associated with an element type
>       "xsl: sequence" must not contain the '<' character.

I tried with XPath 2.0 precedes operator

```
<xsl:sequence select="/Root/*[../H1[2] << .]"/>
```

The below is the code I tried.

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<H1>first</H1>
<p>Test</p>
<H1>second</H1>
<p/>
<p/>
<H1/>
<p/>
<p/>
</Root>
```

**Processing**: I am selecting the preceding element using `<<` operator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="/Root/*[../H1[2] << .]"/>     
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Issue:**

> The value of attribute "select" associated with an element type
>       "xsl:sequence" must not contain the '<' character.

**Expected result:**
    To find the preceding element of H1[2] element by using `<<` operator.

Comment: It is possible to write an equivalent expression using `>>` and this doesn't need to be escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath syntax is `<<` but inside of an XML/XSLT  document you need to escape it as `&lt;&lt;`.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you.  It is working fine.
Below is the syntax i used to get the preceding of H1[2],
<xsl:sequence select="/Root/*[. &lt;&lt; ../H1[2]]"/>

Answer (score 3):

To add to Martin's answer, if you want to avoid the unreadable escaping of `<<` to `&lt;&lt;`, you can simply switch the order of the arguments of the `<<` operator and use `>>` (which doesn't need to be escaped) instead, thus:

**Instead of**:

```
<xsl:sequence select="/Root/*[../H1[2] &lt;&lt; .]"/>
```

**Use**:

```
<xsl:sequence select="/Root/*[. >> ../H1[2]]"/>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Your answer is like The icing on the cake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Venkattammal, Hope this will keep your eyse healthy